# CSS3 + Jquery animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of icons that I want to be visible one by one using animations slideLeft when it scroll down. I'm found this css3 animations

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#

Here is a fiddle of it [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aJLrj/)

[image]

This is my HTML

```
                    <div id="create" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20 slideLeft">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Create an account</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="define" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20 slideLeft">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Define your API</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sync" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20 slideLeft">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Sync the local client</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cloud" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20 slideLeft">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Get data from the cloud</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="scale" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20 slideLeft">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Scale as required</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my CSS for the icons.

```
#create, #define, #sync, #cloud, #scale
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

This is my Jquery.

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#create').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#define').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#sync').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#cloud').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#scale').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
});
```

It's working but my problem is, I want to be visible one by one every 3 or 5 seconds.

Please help

Comment: sharing a fiddle of the same is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
setTimeout(myfunction(), 3000);
```

to call myfunction after 3 secs.
to call recursively you again put line setTimeout(myfunction, 3000); in myfunction.

in myfunction you can first set all images css property "visibility: hidden;" and then change property for perticular image "visibility: visible;"

in your case something like this

```
$(".img-circle").css({visibility: hidden})
$("#cloud .img-circle").css({visibility: visible})
```

your should track which image want to show

hope this is helpful.